# loading data from Pig schema to hive schema using hcatalog

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am trying below queries to load data from pig to hive:

data.txt
1,2.0,3.0,4.0

```
r =  load '/hdfs path/data.txt'  using PigStorage(',') as (a:chararray,b:float,c:float,d:float);

store r into 'db.table_name' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Schema of hive table:
(a string, b float, c float, d float)

The above pig queries throwing below error:

> 2016-07-01 08:43:35,908 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>   2016-07-01 08:43:35,909 [main] ERROR strong textorg.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!

Comment: The above worked for me in pig 0.15, which version of pig you are using?. Also please check of data type compatibility of hive table  against the  pig version's data type.